# Kivy ScreenManager doesn't do anything at all

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I have a really basic Kivy program, one that just has a basic screenmanager and buttons to switch between the screens, except the screenmanager isn't working.
Here's the Python file:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class LoginPage(Screen, Widget):
    pass

class CreateAccountPage(Screen, Widget):
    pass


kv = Builder.load_file('the.kv')
class TheApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LoginPage()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TheApp().run()
```

Here's the .kv file:

```
WindowManager:
    LoginPage:
    CreateAccountPage:

<LoginPage>
    name: 'log'
    Button:
        text: 'log'
        on_release: app.root.current = 'create'

<CreateAccountPage>
    name: 'create'
    Button:
        text: 'create'
        on_release: app.root.current = 'log'
```

When I click the button, it doesn't bring me to the next page, it just does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kv file is loaded twice (once implicitly with default naming convention and the other with explicit `kv = Builder.load_file('the.kv')`). Also the `LoginPage` screen is rooted by the call `return LoginPage()` in `build` method. To correct these, you can define the kv file to any name other than the default name. Below is the corrected snippet of the problematic block:

```
kv = Builder.load_file('the1.kv')
class TheApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv
```

Here the kv file is renamed to `the1.kv`.

The rest of the code is ok.